# How to write a good core architecture for a project in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I'm going to have to write a big system in January with ASP.NET MVC3 / C#, and need to know how to write a system that will **WORK**.  I do have a bit of experience with ASP.NET MVC and C# but would not call myself an expert.  It needs to be extensible so that I can extend it later with new features.  How would one go about this?  Is there books that explains this topic in detail or should I use trial and error?

**In short I need to know good design practice in my code thats extend-able for the future.**

Regards
RaVen

The System will be a community portal with forums ratings etc.  Cant say more than that << Company Policy>>,  The forums I can manage because of plenty open source options... But the rest is up to me.

Comment: I also have to write systems that work, try telling us what type of system

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are asking but this question might help you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656455/building-a-cms-in-asp-net-mvc  another one is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325182/ideas-for-opensource-cms-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: you need for sure a good core architect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Professional ASP.NET MVC 2](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-ASP-NET-MVC-2.productCd-0470643188.html) is a good starting point, though, I would assume that they'll come out with an MVC 3 edition as well.  The [NerdDinner](http://www.nerddinner.com) tutorial contains a lot of ideas on how to structure your application.

Basic advice: work with the MVC architecture, not against it.  Understand your application, especially your data model, and layer that onto your application structure. Typically you'll have a controller per model, but not always.

If you want more detailed advice, you'll need to be more specific about your project. I'd suggest coming up with specific questions about various details of your design as you have them, rather than a single question covering the whole project.  The latter probably won't get the kind of response you desire.

Comment: I have updated my main post.  I see your point but I'm scared of saying to much. Company Policy is a pain.

Answer (score 11):

[SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29) == Great Success

Follow SOLID principles in any project and you'll do well.

Answer (score 5):

With regards to core infrastructure/architechure, SharpArchitecture is a good place to start. It is by no means the perfect solution...BUT they give you a good framework to play with and you can have a working system quickly while learning the concepts that work and don't work over time. Take a look and see what you think. It uses NHibernate, Castle and MVC.

Answer (score 3):

Test Driven development will ensure quality for your project. Be strict with yourself, red green refractor. One of MVCs strengths is that it's easier to test.

Comment: Not strictly architecture, but critical to success in my mind.

Answer (score 2):

you can use my **"awesome"** demo as a start

http://awesome.codeplex.com

Answer (score 1):

If it's going to have to be extensible, make sure you write tests.  You'll save yourself sleepless nights in the long run when you fix something, but ended up breaking the entire system.

As far as how to make things "WORK" - that depends on your ability.  Read, and look to improve things, but don't get caught in premature optimization or it will leave you dead in the water.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your edit and your abilities, it might be wiser to select an open source CMS written in ASP.NET MVC and support it.  Your skills are good enough, it sounds like, to learn how to write modules and be part of a larger community.  You do not sound like you really want to write the whole thing because you are timid about your skills, deadlines, etc.  Whilst learning the ins and outs of a well written piece of software, one day you may choose to write your own or contribute to a core piece of the software.  There are several to choose from see my comment above under your question.

edit:  I also think this will allow you to just start and not worry about every design paradigm people will throw at you for success.

Answer (score 0):

[WhoCanHelpMe](http://whocanhelpme.codeplex.com/) is a nice reference application. It's built upon [S#arp Architecture](http://sharparchitecture.net/) which is a good starting point for an MVC-application using domain driven design. That will also help you on the way with wiring IoC and db-stuff.

Remember that not every example and framework will fit your requirements, so do as jFar said, think SOLID and make your own decisions based on principals.

You should also look into [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/) for extensibility.